# Colouring a TD based on its value

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table and I am trying to give the cells a background colour based on its value. The only issue is that if there is the same part of the word in the td they become the same colour. i.e. - `Intensive` and `Lion Intensive` become the same colour. Is there any way to make this distinct to the word?

```
$('td:contains("M/S Select Farm")').css('background','yellow');
$('td:contains("Lion Free Range")').css('background','Blue');
$('td:contains("Barn")').css('background','Orange');
$('td:contains("Free Range")').css('background','green');
$('td:contains("Lion Intensive")').css('background','Red');
$('td:contains("Intensive")').css('background','White');
```

Comment: can't you just put lion intensive after intensive.

Comment: Do you want it to be `equals` (ie an exact match) rather than `contains`?   So if it's `"really intensive"` it won't be white?